# AWS Node.js Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, amazon-ec2

Facing issue: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 59901
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 65536
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 65536
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 59901
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited

--max_old_space_size is 10GB

We have this configuration of aws ec2 but once 1gb heap memory size our system not working all the process goes to down and need to server restart.
I am using PM2 for process management. There is no any exceptions in the code. Please help me to find root cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I added the *force* command for the build of my react js app in the docker config like this one:

```
RUN npm  run build --force
```